# iPhone URL Scheme: If URL is opened inside In-App Browser then my Application does not open

Tags: iphone, browser, qr-code, url-scheme

We use URL Schemes for our iPhone Application. If a user enters a certain URL in his Browser, then our App opens right away, if installed. If it is not installed then the user is directed to our mobile Website.

We embed these URLs in QR-Codes. So our user just need to scan the barcode, click "open url" and are directed right to our App / mobile Website.

However there is a Problem with some QR-Code-Scanners. For example "QR Code Scanner" from "iHandy Corp" opens the URL inside their own app. And because they open it inside their own app, URL Schemes apparently doenst work anymore. Even though the User has installed our App, he is still directed to our mobile Website.

Has anyone else run into that issue? I just want our users be able to use any QR-Code-Scanner they please und still be directed directly into our app, when they scan our URLs.

Comment: how do you accomplish the "fallback to your mobile website"? could you post a sample of your url scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you can't do anything about it. If the app sends the URL to an internal web view control, and not to the platform to be opened by the browser, it just doesn't work.